# Is there any idea to expand the table to remaining space of pdf page in flutter pdf?

Tags: flutter, printing, pdf-generation

I am trying to create an invoice in flutter using pdfpackage. I am using Table.FromTextArray widget to create table. It automatically grow and accomodate pages depending on list of data. But my requirement is to expand the table to remaining space of page even if the list of data length is less. Suppose I have 2 items in list then there will be only 2 rows , remaining space in the page is blank since table takes only 2 row's space. But I want to grow the table to end of the page. How can I achieve this?

This is the function which creates my invoice table

```
pw.Widget buildTableForSales(List<dynamic> itemData) => pw.Table.fromTextArray(
 tableWidth: pw.TableWidth.max,


 headers: [
   pw.Text("SL NO", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("Item Code", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("Description", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("UNIT", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("QTY", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("Rate", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("Total Amt", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("VAT Amt", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
   pw.Text("Net Amt", style: pw.TextStyle(font: font,fontSize: 7), textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center),
 ],
 columnWidths: {
  // 1: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(10),
 },
 cellAlignments: {
   0: pw.Alignment.center,
   1: pw.Alignment.topLeft,
   2: pw.Alignment.topLeft,
   3: pw.Alignment.topRight,
   4: pw.Alignment.topRight,
   5: pw.Alignment.topRight,
   6: pw.Alignment.topRight,
   7: pw.Alignment.topRight,
 },
 cellStyle: const pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
 headerDecoration: const pw.BoxDecoration(
   border: pw.TableBorder(bottom: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black, width: 1.5)),
 ),
 border: const pw.TableBorder(
   horizontalInside: pw.BorderSide(width: 0, color: PdfColors.white),
   verticalInside: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black),
   top: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black),
   left: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black),
   right: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black),
   bottom: pw.BorderSide(color: PdfColors.black),
 ),
 data: List.generate(
   itemData.length,
       (index) {
     return itemData[index];
   },
 ),


);
```